# Change button background color when ping response fails

Tags: c#

In my app I have a button that shows the status of an access point in my network.  The background of the button is green when launching the app, however when disconnecting the AP the button stays green and not changing to red?

This is the code I am currently using:

```
Ping p = new Ping();
        PingReply r;
        string s;
        s = "192.168.0.8";
        r = p.Send(s);
        if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else if (r.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

When I type in the non responsive IP address and launch the app the button background stays default color (grey)

Not sure where I am going wrong?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are other reasons for no success? It would be best to completely remove the second if and just have else. This would color it red if it failed, no matter how it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the IPStatus isn't TimedOut most of the time.
When testing locally I got IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable, so you will need to change your code to this:

```
else if (r.Status == IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

But I strongly recommend removing the second else if and replacing it with an else so it sets the color to red if the host is unreachable, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I can't add comment

Please debug the r.status value, it may be not IPStatus.TimedOut value so remove else if condition and put only else. (other than not IPStatus.Success response color should be red )

```
if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else 
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```